# DevExpress ASPxRichEdit - The "Cannot read property 'columnOffset' of undefined" JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, webforms, devexpress

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is putting an ASPxRichEdit inside a popup control so when a user double clicks on a job it'll bring up the notes for said job in a popup controller. However the issue I am having is that whenever I put a ASPxRichEdit controller inside an ASPxPopupControl I get the following error: 
[image]

Here is a snippet of the ASPxPopupControl that I am trying to implement

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <dx:ASPxPopupControl Width="1200" Height="600" ID="ASPxPopupControl1" runat="server">
                <ContentCollection>
                    <dx:PopupControlContentControl Width="1200" Height="600">
                        <dx:ASPxRichEdit Width="1000" Height="500" ID="ASPxRichEdit1" runat="server"      WorkDirectory="~\App_Data\WorkDirectory">
                        </dx:ASPxRichEdit>
                    </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                </ContentCollection>
            </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used DX search https://search.devexpress.com/?q=Cannot%20read%20property%20%27columnOffset%27%20of%20undefined&m=SupportCenter and they are informed of this problem. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T198005

Comment: yes I know I am the one who sent that message to them. Thought on the off chance someone here might know a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was a bug in the control, it could not start document processing/calculating while it is invisible (or is placed in an invisible container). This bug is fixed in the context of this ticket: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T198005.

The hotfix is already requested and I believe it will be available in the nearest days.